# Updating a page after making an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a response from an API when I post data to it. When I hit the API, the response should be updated right way in my blade.php. When I post to the API at the moment the data is saved but I only see it after I refresh my page. Then the newly added data appears among the existing ones.

How do I just update my blade with the newly added data without refreshing the page?

```html
<form id="presentUpdateForm" method="POST" action="/comment">
  @csrf
  <div class="card" id="comment-">
    @foreach($results_comments['body']['data'] as $comment)
      <div id="comment_section" class="card-body d-flex b-b">
        <div>
          <p>{{$comment['text']}}</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" rows="3" placeholder="Your comment..."></textarea>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-3">
      <button type="button" id="btnComment" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
//updat form submit
$('#btnComment').on('click', function(e) {
  var data = $('#presentUpdateForm').serialize();
  var postURL = '/comment';
  console.log(postURL);
  $.ajax({
    url: postURL,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.body.text);
      $('#presentUpdateForm').trigger("reset");
    },
    error: function(data) {
      // var respone = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
      alert('Error');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to add the HTML to the DOM. As you've not shown us exactly what this should look like to be able to give you an example, I'd suggest you research some of jQuery's DOM manipulation methods, such as [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append), or [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html)

Comment: can you show please full page code with html of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update your blade.php, because that's server-side. However you can update the DOM using JavaScript.

You can do this through jQuery using the following in you success callback function:

```
$("#comment-").append('<div class="card-body d-flex b-b"><div><p>' + data.body.text + '</p></div></div>');
```

This assumes that what you want to add to the page is the 'text' property of you response.